# Mouse is frozen on one window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, minecraft

I am on a Linux 14.04 64 bit. Here is more info:

Processor : Intel® Core™ i7 CPU K 875 @ 2.93GHz × 8

Graphics : Gallium 0.4 on NV92

---

My problem is that, when I'm playing an App called,"Minecraft," every 3-10 minutes, my game freezes. So I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I selected Google Chrome and it turned out my whole desktop didn't freeze. But then, I didn't see my mouse cursor anywhere. My thought was that it was stuck in the game window. So I went back and waited a few minutes, but the game wouldn't unfreeze. So I had to restart my computer.

Is there anyway I can take the mouse cursor off the game? or kill it? What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To kill Minecraft when it crashes you have two options, which one works for you depends on what version of Minecraft you are playing, your Linux distribution, driver configuration, and other variables -- it's best to just try Method 1 and then try Method 2 if the first one fails.

**Method 1:**
Type ALT+F2 to enter a command or CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal to enter a command. Enter the command `xkill` and then click the mouse. This method is less likely to work as the program `xkill` needs to grab the cursor and Minecraft currently has it. It is, however, less blunt than the other method.

**Method 2:**
Type ALT+F2 to enter a command or CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal to enter a command. Enter the command `killall java`. This method is almost guaranteed to work, but it will kill all programs that use Java -- not just Minecraft.